# I copied the "live" version of my VS2015 Website back to my desktop and lost all codebehinds

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I published my asp.net forms website with C# code behind.  My computer crashed and I had to copy back the website to my hard drive.  Everything works both locally and on the web. Visual studio 2015 just won't show any files with the "aspx.cs"  Nothing in solution explorer

An Example page Topper is <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="B.aspx.cs" Inherits="ServiceChecker.B" %>

There is even a green squiggly line under CodeBehind="B.aspx.cs" and the message on mouseover says "File B.aspx.cs was not found"  I have code in the file that is working though.

Thank you for looking at this.

Jason

Comment: You could use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) on the DLL as a guide in rewriting the missing .cs files, but this time also putting them into a source control system like git on another machine, so if it ever happens again you can just clone the repository.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  The project was a "learning project" I am trying to teach myself C# and ASP.net.  So this will be a learning experience.  I will keep a backup onf dropbox.  I am not sure how git works but I will look into it.

Comment: Do look into git. A backup will only let you restore what was in the backup. Git will let you do that, share code, mix in changes from other people, compare changes, undo a change you realised was bad, find what changes happened to bits of code to understand why they were written the way they were, send recommended changes to other people's projects. When you start with the basics you'll have the safety if incidents like this happen again. Learn a little more and you'll appreciate it as as vital a tool as your text editor and compiler, and that stays with you when coding in other languages too

Comment: https://git-scm.com/video/what-is-version-control https://git-scm.com/video/get-going https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Holy Carp... What a nice thing... It is free too! Wow.  I am a hobbyist and kinda just program for fun, but I will use this tool next time I make a large project in ASP.Net.   Thank you again

Comment: It can be seem at first less important to hobbyists, since a lot of its importance only comes in when you are working with others, but once it becomes part of how you work you gain a lot on even very small projects, so I use it for any personal project I'm not going to throw away the same day (which I do sometimes with experiments). Also, once you are more accomplished as a hobbyist, contributing to open-source projects can be particularly rewarding (as someone who is both a professional and also a hobbyist in my time off, I find it so) and that needs the basics of source control.

Comment: Hi Joe, Git seems a little too complicated for me.  Is periodically just copying my whole folder ok to do with Visual Studio 2015?  I just make small websites for family and Church.  I just want a way to go back in case I screw something up :)   I am going to google this some more. But again thank you for taking the time to answer my noobness.

Comment: Hello again.  I found an add-on program that will let me back-up and it even zips the files.  It is called DPACK.  Maybe you would like it too!  Thanks again for all your kind help

Comment: Who's Joe? ;) Copying the whole folder will do the job as far as protecting against a failure like this (as long as you copy it somewhere that won't get hit by the same incident), and certainly better than nothing. Git is complicated, but like many complicated things, it's possible to start small (I still don't know a lot of stuff about git myself, but I do know enough to make use of it every day) and I'd still recommend it (a lot of people would say Mercurial is easier for beginners, though a lot disagree, and I've not used it enough to have an opinion). I'd still recommend learning it, …

Comment: … but of course, there's so many useful and interesting things to learn, and only so much time in the day!

Comment: Dear Jon, oh my goodness, I am so sorry to have called you Joe. Thank you again for answering my question and your advice.

Comment: No worries, I was only teasing.